# The best way to do multiple ajax calls with RxJS6

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs6

I tried to make RxJS epic which will basically do loop over an API end point and concatenate results into one big array, due to fact that API allows maximum of 100 elements as response I want to collect all elements and ideally sort them before I put it as payload to redux

```
const fetchData = action$ =>
action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_DATA),
    mergeMap(action =>
        ajax(`localhost:8001/data?page=${action.payload.pages}&per_page=${MAX_PER_PAGE}`).pipe(
            map(datas => fetchDataSuccess(datas)),
            retry(2),
            catchError(error => of(fetchDataFailed()))
        )
    )
);
```

this snippet works and I made a work around in my component where I basically do iteration over page numbers and call this fetch data for each page number, I do not like this but didn't found what would be better approach to do this in epic itself.

Tried also to dispatch additional action and do sort in reducer once when all pages are loaded, but I'm pretty sure that RxJS is more powerful and there is a way to do it directly in epic.

I'm pretty much idealess at this stage, anyone see some better way to do multi Ajax cals and combine all results into one big array?

Comment: Have a look at the `expand` example in this article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-expand-a5f8b41a3602

Comment: @cartant this looks like what I need, I browse RxJS specs but to be honest it's so unhandy and weird and I found out that people are learning it from posts like this :( Thanks ;)

Comment: @cartant this is it, I made some changes on my API to send as part of header next URL, and it works like a charm ;)

Comment: The blog post link specified above is no longer valid. The canonical link to the post is: https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/